# Как получить текущую дату с учётом локали с помошью new Date() с помошью Java Script?

Tags: javascript

у меня не получается получить c помошью new Date() местное время, с учётом часового пояса. Как мне это сделать ?

Comment: а как вы пытались?

Comment: new Date().toUTCString()

Comment: Так вы же UTC сами используете! Без часового пояса.

Comment: Утром проснулся, убрал .toUTCString() и получил то что надо